# How to line up the contents of a variable

Tags: linux, bash, shell, for-loop, process

I run the following commands:

```
cd /proc
process=$(ls | egrep '[0-9]')
echo $process
```

I get the following output:

```
1
108
109
8130
```

However, I want to have the following output:

```
1 108 109 8130
```

How can I do that?

Comment: someone with so many points (some sort of admin) will come and say > you didnt add sample and output. :))

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't get it :)

Comment: Indeed, please edit your question provide a small sample input and the desired output for that sample input.

Comment: not an admin but I'll play ... OP: take a look at [How to create a minimal, reproducible exampl](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example); in particular, show a sample of the contents of your variable, what your script is (incorrectly) generating, and what you're trying to (correctly) generate

Comment: Please see edited post

Comment: The listed commands will give the desired output (although there are better ways to do it) unless something unusual has been set. Did you change `IFS`? Going through the process of creating a minimal, reproducible example will probably reveal the cause.

Answer (score 1):

Since your variable `process` is only be used in the `echo`, I would simplify your script to

```
cd /proc
echo *[0-9]*
```

If you really need the process names for postprocessing in a later step, I would store them in an array:

```
processes=(*[0-9]*)
```

With this approach, you can display them in a single line using

```
echo "${processes[@]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use `echo` command as:

```
...
process=$(echo [0-9]*)
...
```

Comment: Nearly correct. This shows only processnames **starting** with a digit.